# Uniform Random Numbers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to understand what this code does. I am going through some examples about numpy and plotting and I can't figure out what `u` and `v` are. I know `u` is an array of two arrays each with size 10000. What does  `v=u.max(axis=0)` do? Is the `max` function being invoked part of the standard python library? When I plot the histogram I get a pdf defined by 2x as opposed to a normal uniform distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
u=rand.uniform(0,1,[2,10000])
v=u.max(axis=0)
plt.figure()
plt.hist(v,100,normed=1,color='blue')
plt.ylim([0,2])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

`u.max()`, or equivalently `np.max(u)`, will give you *the* maximum value in the array - i.e. a single value. It's the Numpy function here, not part of the standard library. You often want to find the maximum value along a particular axis/dimension and that's what is happening here.

U has shape `(2,10000)`, and `u.max(axis=0)` gives you the max along the `0` axis, returning an array with shape `(10000,)`. If you did `u.max(axis=1)` you would get an array with shape `(2,)`.

Simple illustration/example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> a.max(axis=0)
array([3, 4])
>>> a.max(axis=1)
array([2, 4])
>>> a.max()
4
```

Comment: I'm still confused what axis = 0 and axis = 1 means geometrically. In your example, why does a.max(axis=0) = array([3,4])?

Comment: Think of it as choosing "maximum along column" versus "maximum along column" (axis=1)

Comment: axis =0 is maximum along rows?

Comment: @lord12 - `a.max(axis=0)` is the maximum along each column, while `a.max(axis=1)` is the maximum along each row.

Answer (score 3):

first three lines you load in different modules (libraries that are relied apon in the rest of the code). you load `numpy` which is a numerical library, `numpy.random` which is a library that does a lot of great work to create random numbers and `matplotlib` allows for plotting functions.

the rest is described here:

`np.random.seed(123)`

A computer does not really generate a random number rather picks a number from a long list of numbers (for a more correct explanation of how this is done http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation). In essence if you want to reproduce the work with the same random numbers the computer needs to know where in this list of numbers to start picking numbers. This is what this line of code does. If anybody else runs the same piece of code now you end up with the same 'random' numbers.

`u=rand.uniform(0,1,[2,10000])`

This generates 10000 random numbers twice that are distributed between 0 and 1. This is uniform distribution so it is equally likely to get any point between 0 and 1. (Again more information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) ). You are creating two arrays within an array. This can be checked by doing: `len(u)` and `len(u[0])`.

`v=u.max(axis=0)`

The `u.max?` command in iPython refers you to the docs. It is basically select a max and the axis determines how the max is chosen. Try the following:

```
a = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
np.amax(a, axis=0) # gives array([2, 3])
np.amax(a, axis=1) # gives array([1, 3])
```

The rest of the code is meant to set the histogram plot. There are 100 bins in total in the histogram and the bars will be colored blue. The maximum height on the histogram y-axis is 2 and normed will guarantee that at least one sample will be in every bin.

I can't clearly make up what the true purpose or application of the code was. But this is en essence what it is doing.